# Find error in the below question

Tags: error

> A cup of coffee (1) / is an excellent complement (2) / to smoked salmon (3) / no error (4)

According to me error should be in 3 as it should be" a smoked salmon "but the answer provided is no error. Is the answer provided wrong?

Comment: You should add why you think 3 should be "a smoked salmon". It's still wrong, but it might make for a better explanation.

Comment: The error is even recommending drinking coffee with a smoked salmon dish. "*A cup of coffee is NOT an excellent complement to smoked salmon*" is a much better sentence  :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I have since tried this and heartily concur that smoked salmon and coffee are not *complementary* flavors.  Perhaps they meant that the coffee is a nice way to *cleanse the palate* between bites, or that coffee goes well with the typical *accoutrements* of smoke salmon, like certain cheeses, but I cannot recommend coffee and salmon in the same mouthful.

Comment: @Andrew I was wondering, wouldn't "accompaniment" be a more appropriate term for a drink that is consumed with a meal?

Comment: @Mari-LouA  In this case I think my use of "accoutrement" is *ironic*, since it's an uncommon term that ordinarily refers to *equipment*, or *tools*, not food.  Although I don't think "accompaniment" is quite the right word either.  More common is "go with", as in, *"Coffee **goes with** a donut -- or, more likely,* donuts *"*.  However with wine (and some other alcoholic beverages)  you will often see "pair", as in, *"What vintage is best **paired** with this spinach and arugula salad with heirloom tomatoes, maple-infused pistachios, and Himalayan sea salt?"*

Comment: It's not unreasonable to ask if it is a good idea to *pair* coffee with smoked salmon.

Comment: @Andrew just the mere thought makes my tastebuds pucker.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to use *complement*.

> A is a **complement to** B.
>
> A is a **complement of** B.
>
> A **complements** B.

Unfortunately you have to memorize these and recognize them when they appear.

Your answer would be correct if the subject were plural, and if the sentence didn't include the "to be" verb before "excellent complement".  For example:

> Many glasses of wine nicely **complement** a heartfelt conversation.

As written the "to be" verb turns "complement" into a noun:

> Many glasses of wine *are* a nice **complement to** a heartfelt conversation.

Additionally, "smoked salmon" is both a *countable* and an *uncountable* noun.  You can have both a single smoked salmon (the whole fish) or some quantity of smoked salmon.  Which is meant depends on context, but in general you'll see the uncountable far more often, since you'll rarely want to serve an entire smoked salmon (unless you really like the stuff).  In your example question, I would assume they mean an undefined and uncountable quantity of smoked salmon, and not use any article.  Related example:

> I will never turn down **smoked salmon** (uncountable) and cream cheese (uncountable) on a bagel (countable).

Personally I don't see coffee going with smoked salmon, but that's just my opinion.  I should try it and find out.

(Edit)  In my opinion, coffee and smoked salmon are not *complementary* flavors.  However, it may be that coffee is a nice way to [*cleanse the palate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cleanse%20the%20palate) between bites of salmon.

Comment: Nope. salmon is oily and coffee is not drunk to cleanse the palate between one bite and another. That would be the job for a wine. A sorbet, or pre dessert,  is served after the main course but before dessert. It's tangy, tart fresh taste acts like a gateway to a  sweeter dish.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I can't argue with that.  :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem?

> A cup of coffee - I think no problem with this. 
>  *salmon* is [a countable noun](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/salmon) but as a dish, it is uncountable or a [mass noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/salmon) 
>    something can be a [*complement to* something (def: 3)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/complement)

No error! :)

Comment: @java I meant that only. Anyway edited

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the quote is supposed to be a complete English sentence, the error lies in region (3). The words are fine (disregarding the whole business of whether coffee complements salmon), but there should be a full stop (period) or exclamation mark etc at the end of the sentence.

Incidentally, no article is required before *salmon*. This holds for the coffee as well - you could drop "A cup of" and still end up with a valid sentence, provided you punctuate the end of the sentence.

Comment: The missing period/full stop is probably a transcription error on the OP's part.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've answered the question as asked :P . (And included a comment about determiners, which touches on the substance of the OP's concern.) Besides, the quote is from a test where errors are deliberately inserted. Leaving out a full stop is a real possibility. :)

Comment: http://studymaterials.examsrider.com/ssc-mts-general-english-spotting-errors-10/ The "A cup of" is perfectly fine, you could have said that "a smoked salmon" means the entire fish, which would be unlikely because salmons can be pretty huge!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yup, determiners change the sense somewhat, but in this case, either, both or none is fine. I was just pointing out that not having a determiner before *salmon* wasn't a problem.